# trying to set ssl using docker, restcomm & letsencrypt

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, restcomm

dears,

I am trying to add ssl to my restcomm application.
I installed a docker regularly and a broken https is working fine, the default one.
Then i tried letsencrypt and generated a .jks file using keytool.
i followed this tutorial o

http://documentation.telestax.com/connect/configuration/Restcomm%20-%20Enable%20HTTPS%20secure%20connector%20on%20JBoss%20AS%207%20or%20EAP%206.html#secure

and  restarted the server and nothing happened.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use authorized certificate (.jks file) there are 2 options on restcomm-docker:

1. Mount the jks file from the host: e.g. 
   -v host/location/.jks:/opt/Restcomm-JBoss-AS7/standalone/configuration/restcomm-combined.jks
2. pull from a remote location using :  
   `CERTCONFURL JKS file URL location
   CERTREPOUSR Username for authentication if needed.
   CERTREPOPWRD Password for authentications if needed.`

*As well you need to set the variables : 
`- SECURESSL=AUTH
- TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD Set the password to use for RestComm to configure the certificate for HTTPS and SIP TLS
- TRUSTSTORE_ALIAS Set the Alias to use for RestComm to configure the certificate for HTTPS and SIP TLS`

More info here (under "HTTPS related configuration"): [restcomm-docker configuraion documentation](http://documentation.telestax.com/connect/configuration/docker/Restcomm%20-%20Docker%20Environment%20Variables.html#docker-environment)